# putty aborts process while shutting down

Tags: unix-shell

I'm newby so the question is simple. After I connected to server via putty I want to execute some command. Suppose that command will be performed for long time (e.g. extracting files from large archive or mysql backup). Is there a way to execute a command in such a way that it wount be aborted after I close putty!

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way is to run `screen`, execute your command, then detach using `^A, D`. When you ssh into your machine again, run `screen -r` and your session will be reattached just as you left it. Screen can also do much more, check out the [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) to see what's possible.

Comment: Prefer tmux, but much the same idea.

Answer (score 5):

There's a package called "screen" that needs to be installed on the host you're logged into. This has nothing to do with putty, or ssh - this is the way Unix shells work. When you disconnect a shell, you're logged off, and all your processes get a HUP signal. Most (all) processes shut down. "Screen" makes your shell continue running, so you may reconnect later.

Answer (score 4):

Yes! You should background the process and disown it.

So, if I wanted to run the command "foo", I'd do `nohup foo & && disown`.  The nohup keeps it from dying when SIGHUP is sent to it and sends the output to a file, and disown removes the parent reference so it doesn't die when the spawning shell does.

Comment: This will work as well, although you won't be able to interact with it and hopefully can get everything you need out of the logfile.